# LinkedIn API access

Tags: linkedin-api

I need access to LinkedIn profile API. As one can read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api.

"The use of this API is restricted to those developers approved by LinkedIn and subject to applicable data restrictions in their agreements."

However, there is nothing about how to become approved by LinkedId. I found this https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply but this is also unclear to which program i should apply.

I also tried to just create LinkedIn app at https://www.linkedin.com/developers/, but during process there was no step to request api permission, and after the creation i see just laconic note "No permissions added" and no ability to request any.

Could one of you please help me? Thx a lot in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/permissions?context=linkedin/context

Comment: @taurus05 i visited this link before i posted the question. Problem is that it says " If your application needs to access APIs that are not member specific, use the Client Credential Flow " and from other hand about member authentication it says : "Use this flow if you are requesting access to a member's account to use their data and make requests on their behalf. " The API i need is member specific, but i do need or want users to authenticate my call. I want to be able to grab member publicly accessible data by : GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{person ID}).

Comment: @pociej if you go to linkedin.com/developers after logging in and going to My Apps -> Your App -> Auth tab do you see anything under "Permissions" section? Mine shows:
 r_emailaddress
3-legged member permission
r_liteprofile
3-legged member permission
w_member_social
3-legged member permission

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to login and retrieve firstname, lastname and email then you need to create a developer account related to a company page, and then verify it, steps are very easy : https://www.linkedin.com/developers/

However if you need more, like retrieving 1st contacts, profile, you should apply on the program corresponding to the permissions you need to unlock, most likely Marketing Developer:

[Marketing Developer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/getting-started#what-permissions-are-available)

> r_1st_connections_size, r_basicprofile (among others)

You will however need to fulfill the following conditions:

- Do you have a verified business?
- Do you have an established use case?
- Does your use case align with our API capabilities?
  (Our APIs may not be used to enhance sign-in with LinkedIn, collect and store member data, or display social feeds)
- Do you agree to comply with the LinkedIn Marketing Developer Platform terms of service?

The first one preventing startup and developers to access.

[Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/learning/overview/)

> LinkedIn Learning APIs are designed to represent LinkedIn Learning content in a unified and extensible format. The endpoints can be used to integrate LinkedIn Learning catalog metadata and search into your application (...)

---

That said, **I DO NOT RECOMMEND** or endorse the policy of LinkedIn to make it so difficult to use their API. Since 2019 they have also broken backward compatibility while migrating from version 1 to version 2.

**It is clearly not healthy to base your code on a company that 1/ Makes breaking changes and 2/ Does provide very little functions from their API.**

These breaking changes are the direct consequence of [LinkedIn losing a lawsuit in 2019 over access to user profiles](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-microsoft-linkedin-profiles/microsofts-linkedin-loses-appeal-over-access-to-user-profiles-idUSKCN1VU21W). Since they cannot legally prevent developers to access their public data, they have decided to make it very hard to be scraped, and restricted the use of their API to "protect their business".

Answer (score 0):

Open permissions are available to all developers for the following:

```
r_liteprofile # Member Auth: retrieve (authenticated member's) name, headline, and photo
r_emailaddress # Member Auth: retrieve primary email address
w_member_social # Member Auth: post, comment, and like posts on behalf of a member
```

You must request access for learning, marketing, and sales permissions through their website.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-07